# How to do find() / where() in associated models

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm playing with model associations in sails and I'm curious if it's possible to make a query base on the associated field.

Example:

```
User.js
 attributes:{
  classes: { collection: 'Class', via: 'students' }
 }
Class.js
 attributes: {
  type: ...
  students: { collection: 'User', via: 'classes'}
 }
```

Is there a way to retrieve specific Classes of a Student base on the type of class because right now everything is being returned when I use `.populate()`. (maybe similar with the logic below)

```
User
 .findOne({name: 'StudentA'})
 .populate('classes')
 .where({'classes.type':['type1', 'type2']})
 .then(....)
```

Thanks

Comment: Not directly helpful to your question...But if you are using a many-to-many, I believe you need to specify `dominant:true` on one side of the relation.

Comment: As of v0.10-rc5, `dominant` is only required if the models are using different connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `where` clause to your `populate` like so:

```
User
 .findOne({name: 'StudentA'})
 .populate('classes', {where: {type: ['type1', 'type2']}})
 .exec(...)
```

In addition to `where`, you can also use `skip`, `limit` and `sort` in the second argument to `populate`.

Keep in mind this is still (as of this posting) in beta, so if you find any issues where it seems to not be working correctly, please post them to the [Waterline GitHub issues forum](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues?state=open).

Comment: Thanks @Scott, but is it also possible to filter the User base on the related table values?

Comment: No. Your best bet there is to do `Class.find({type: ['type1', 'type2']}).populate('users')`, then loop through the result and merge the arrays of users together.